# Manually install Device plugin (and others) into cordova 3.0

Tags: android, ios, cordova

Phonegap/Cordova 3.0 has moved into a modular design starting with version 3.0. For example, to call the `device.version` API, you need to include the Device plugin into your project.

Anyone can provide me with clear instructions on how to install the Device (or any other) cordova API plugin into a new iOS project (using XCode) AND Android (using Eclipse)?

All I could find is details using Node.js and/or PlugMan. Needing an automated script to do the basic job of adding a plugin is undesirable to me, as I do not like processes doing things I don't understand (behind the scene).

In the past (cordova 2.9), I did the following to add a third-party plugin in (say Android) that worked perfectly:

1. Put the plugin .java code into the /src folder
2. Put the plugin .js code in my www folder
3. Import the .js file into index.html
4. Add the `feature` tag in config.xml
5. Call the plugin in Javascript

I never added plugins in iOS before.

However, I assumed the above process should work just fine for cordova-based plugins, but it did not. Up to this point, I did not try Android, but I tried iOS with no luck.

I included `CDVDevice.h` and `CDVDevice.m` in /plugins folder. Also I imported the device.js into index.html, and modified config.xml! I will try Android only after finishing iOS.

Please, if you know how to do this manually let me know.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 14):

You can do it this way, download the plugin locally to your machine then run this code

```
cordova plugin add <id located in plugin.xml> --searchpath <local path to plugin>
```

This will install the plugin into your project

Answer (score 10):

I ran into the same issue.

In fact, the plugin system has not changed much.

I added the date picker plugin for Android just now :

- add classes (.m .h for iphone, .java for android)
- add js files where you want
- add link to js files in your index.html
- edit config.xml (path depends on which OS you used) :

Instead of adding plugins between plugins tags :

```
<plugin name="DatePickerPlugin" value="com.phonegap.plugins.DatePickerPlugin"/>
```

You will add a feature (what a revolution !) like this :

```
<feature name="DatePickerPlugin" >
    <param name="android-package" value="com.phonegap.plugins.DatePickerPlugin"/>
</feature>
```

And that is it !

If you are not sure about the OS syntax for param name, you can add a default cordova plugin using a command as this one :

```
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git
```

More info there :
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface

Comment: this works for what is asked in question, but how to add a self developed plugin, which is at local machine? cordova plugin add <path_to_local_file_system> and that what structure it needs?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, this no longer works for ALL plugins in cordova 3.0. Try for example the cordova Device plugin (which used to be a built-in API but now is a plugin). Up to this point, I found one reason why that is: the provided device.js file no longer has the line: 'define("cordova/plugin/android/device", function(require, exports, module) {'. This line is now automatically added by plugman! I wish someone can provide specific details on what exactly does plugman do! +1 though.

Comment: Basically plugman do the same job. It copy files into your src folders (.java/.h .m and .js files) and it adds a feature in your config.xml. You will find a plugin.xml file which do the process (like an ant file).

Answer (score 7):

I was getting an error when I tried to add a plugin using the following command:

```
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git
```

Although, git clone was working, so I downloaded the plugin into a local folder and added it by using

```
cordova plugin add my/local/folder
```

Answer (score 0):

For Android we just need to create the plugin (Java class extending CordovaPlugin) and then add the item into config.xml (res/xml/..) you are done.

```
 <feature name="Calendar">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.package.Calendar" />
    </feature>
```

assume Calendar as your plugin name
Also make sure to add link to js file

Thanks