# cordova add plugin - unable to access

Tags: plugins, cordova, addition

I am trying to add a plugin to Cordova via

```
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git
```

git itself seems to run fine. Running the following works:

```
git clone "https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git" "D:\Temp\plugman-tmp1390234462383"
```

This is what is used in plugins.js line 43 (var cmd = util.format(...)).

The error I receive using the cordova plugin add ... is:

```
Calling plugman.fetch on plugin "https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git"
Fetching plugin from "https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git"...
Fetching plugin via git-clone command: git clone "https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git" "D:\Temp\plugman-tmp1390235833828"

C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: Fetching plugin failed: Error: Command failed: Cloning into 'D:\Temp\plugman-tmp1390234462383'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git/': Failed connect to git-wip-us.apache.org:443; No error

at C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\plugin.js:90:41
at _rejected (C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:808:24)
at C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:834:30
at Promise.when (C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:1079:31)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:752:41)
at C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:574:44
at flush (C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

Any idea?

Some more information:

I am going through a proxy, but I set this for git and for npm. I installed Cordova via "npm install cordova" and the project via "cordova create TestApp", I added platforms via "cordova platform add android" and I can run the app on the emulator.

I even tried "phonegap local plugin add https..." with the same result.

All that is missing for me is to add plugins.

Comment: Can you run the `cordova plugin add` command with `-d` flag to get more output and see if the error message has improved? Can you try doing `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device-motion` and see if it's different (Using the plugin name instead of the actual git url).  Also, try just deleting the `\cordova\` folder inside your `node_modules` folder. This will clear the 'cordova cache' which can sometimes get messed up when there is an upgrade and/or problem with npm (last week the servers were a little goofy.) Finally, why is your temp drive in `D://` but your commands in `C://`?

Comment: I added the additional lines to the output, which is basically the first three lines (Calling plugman.fetch....)

Comment: "cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device-motion" throws a ETIMEDOUT

Comment: I have set all TEMP path variables to D:\Temp and the user dir is still inside C:/Users/...

Comment: @MBillau: Which folder do you want me to delete exactly. If I delete the cordova foulder inside my node_modules then cordova is gone and it says "Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\bin\cordova'"

Comment: I would probably delete the AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/cordova directory, and then do `npm install cordova -g` again to get a fresh install of Cordova + all the tools. However it says in the logs "Failed to connected to git..." - I know you said you have configured the git and npm proxy settings, maybe there is a problem with Cordova reading/using these settings...

Comment: That's my guess, but how could I set these, as I can add platforms, but not the git part.

Comment: I don't think cordova-cli has any way to configure proxy settings as it should just use whichever settings NPM and git have. I guess you could download the plugins with git yourself and then pass the path of that plugin into the CLI when you use the `add` command.

Comment: @MBillau: Could you write your last answer as a real answer, so I can mark it as best answer? It works. Not nice, but does the job for me :)

Comment: Sure thing. Yeah I've had to do this once or twice too, it's not really horrible but pretty annoying.

Comment: I had the same problem. Please see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25314991/1187896) for the solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes a Cordova update will cause problems with npm and will corrupt the "cordova cache" that NPM uses to quickly download different Cordova versions. I know there were problems with the server pushing the latest Cordova plugins to NPM, so maybe this is why you're having trouble.

I'd suggest deleting `/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/cordova` direct in its entirety, than installing a fresh new copy with `npm install -g cordova`. This shouldn't remove any of your Cordova projects, it will just download a fresh set of the tools. When you run `cordova` commands, it might take longer the first time since the tools will have to go to the git repo's and fetch the content fresh.

Comment: Did not help me. But as you got two upvotes so far, seems to help other :)

Comment: It also helped me. It worked, despite I don't understant exactly what happened :)

Answer (score 1):

Tried clearing the cordova cache by deleting the folder as suggested by @mbillau but that didn't help. I search for the plugin where I was getting the error and tried installing through command line but got the same error message. Finally the solution that worked for me:

1. open important files in your IDE
2. open Cordova plugins
3. replace all "https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/" with "https://git.apache.org/"

and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Replacing "https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/" with "https://github.com/apache/" in Cordova plugins (plugins.properties) resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Replace "git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf7" with "github.com/apache/"
Like @Max said.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the apache site (either https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/, https://gitbox.org/repos/asf/, or https://git.apache.org/) I only see commit logs instead of the sources.

The sources can be found on GitHub. This worked for me:
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device.git